# CodeIgniter Authentication Library for Beginners?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone recommend a great CodeIgniter Registration/Login/Logout library for beginners to web development?

I read on stackoverflow that Redux was highly recommended at one time. What is the current recommendation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend Ion Auth Library which can be found here:

http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

It is very secure, a lot of good features for an auth library, and developed by a really nice guy.

Comment: +1 for this one. Ion Auth carries on the mantle for Redux Auth and continues to add awesome features while keeping the library very simple and as light as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Brennan and Phil. Can you recommend any tutorials for beginners? I've searched and have not found any as yet. 
However, this page explained the features clearly: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Ion_Auth_-_Lightweight_Auth_System/

Comment: Ion Auth is fairly easy to understand even for beginners. I'd suggest taking a look at the code and samples. And then creating a simple app based on it.